# Immutable Keyed Set

Tags: c#, api, hash-map, set, immutability

### Description

> An immutable keyed set is a readonly collection of elements without
>   duplicates or null values having each of the elements linked to
>   exactly one key.

#### Example

> This simple [example of an Exact Cover](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_cover#Representations) solution has a constraint
>   set \$\{ 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 \}\$ covered by candidates \$\{ B,D,F \}\$.
>
> - \$B: \{ 1,4 \}\$
> - \$D: \{ 3,5,6 \}\$
> - \$F: \{ 2,7 \}\$

This could be presented as an immutable keyed set. What's imperative is that each of the constraints \$X\$ only has 1 matching candidate \$S\$.

[image]

#### Usage

```
[TestMethod]
public void Usage()
{
    IReadOnlyKeyedSet<char, int> set = new ImmutableKeyedSet<char, int>(Data());
    var sb = new StringBuilder();

    foreach (var entry in set)
    {
        sb.AppendLine($"{entry.Key}: {string.Join(",", entry)}");
    }

    var rendered = sb.ToString();

    // B: 1,4
    // D: 3,5,6
    // F: 2,7
}

private static IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<char, IEnumerable<int>>> Data()
{
    yield return new KeyValuePair<char, IEnumerable<int>>('B', new[] { 1, 4 });
    yield return new KeyValuePair<char, IEnumerable<int>>('D', new[] { 3, 5, 6 });
    yield return new KeyValuePair<char, IEnumerable<int>>('F', new[] { 2, 7 });
}
```

The purpose is to guard against an invalid set.

```
private static IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<char, IEnumerable<int>>> Data()
{
    yield return new KeyValuePair<char, IEnumerable<int>>('B', new[] { 1, 2, 4 });
    yield return new KeyValuePair<char, IEnumerable<int>>('D', new[] { 3, 5, 6 });
    yield return new KeyValuePair<char, IEnumerable<int>>('F', new[] { 2, 7 });
}
```

The above should throw:

```
"Duplicate value 2 on key F and B"
```

---

### Code

Interface `IReadOnlyKeyedSet<TKey, TElement>`

```
public interface IReadOnlyKeyedSet<TKey, TElement> : ILookup<TKey, TElement>
{
    IEqualityComparer<TKey> KeyComparer { get; }
    IEqualityComparer<TElement> ElementComparer { get; }
    bool ContainsValue(TElement value);
    bool TryGetValues(TKey key, out IEnumerable<TElement> values);
    bool TryGetKey(TElement value, out TKey key);
}
```

Implementation `ImmutableKeyedSet<TKey, TElement>`

```
public class ImmutableKeyedSet<TKey, TElement> : IReadOnlyKeyedSet<TKey, TElement>
{
    private readonly Dictionary<TKey, Bucket> buckets;
    private readonly Dictionary<TElement, TKey> elements;

    public ImmutableKeyedSet(
        IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, IEnumerable<TElement>>> keyedSet,
        IEqualityComparer<TKey> keyComparer = null,
        IEqualityComparer<TElement> elementComparer = null)
    {
        KeyComparer = keyComparer ?? EqualityComparer<TKey>.Default;
        ElementComparer = elementComparer ?? EqualityComparer<TElement>.Default;
        buckets = new Dictionary<TKey, Bucket>(KeyComparer);
        elements = new Dictionary<TElement, TKey>(ElementComparer);
        Set(keyedSet ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(keyedSet)));
    }

    public IEqualityComparer<TKey> KeyComparer { get; }

    public IEqualityComparer<TElement> ElementComparer { get; }

    public IEnumerable<TElement> this[TKey key] => buckets[key];

    public int Count => buckets.Count;

    public bool Contains(TKey key) => buckets.ContainsKey(key);

    public bool ContainsValue(TElement value) => elements.ContainsKey(value);

    public IEnumerator<IGrouping<TKey, TElement>> GetEnumerator()
        => buckets.Values.GetEnumerator();

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => GetEnumerator();

    public bool TryGetValues(TKey key, out IEnumerable<TElement> values)
    {
        var bucket = FindBucketByKey(key);
        values = bucket == null ? default : bucket.Values;
        return bucket != null;
    }

    public bool TryGetKey(TElement value, out TKey key)
    {
        var bucket = FindBucketByValue(value);
        key = bucket == null ? default : bucket.Key;
        return bucket != null;
    }

    private Bucket FindBucketByValue(TElement value)
    {
        if (elements.TryGetValue(value, out var key))
        {
            return buckets[key];
        }

        return null;
    }

    private Bucket FindBucketByKey(TKey key)
    {
        if (buckets.TryGetValue(key, out var bucket))
        {
            return bucket;
        }

        return null;
    }

    private void Set(IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, IEnumerable<TElement>>> keyedSet)
    {
        foreach (var entry in keyedSet)
        {
            var key = entry.Key;
            if (key == null) throw new ArgumentException("Key must be set");
            var bucket = FindBucketByKey(key);
            if (bucket != null)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException($"Duplicate key {key}");
            }
            bucket = new Bucket(key);
            if (entry.Value == null) throw new ArgumentException("Value must be set");
            var values = new HashSet<TElement>(entry.Value);
            foreach (var value in values)
            {
                if (value == null) throw new ArgumentException(
                    "Value must not contain null");
                var valueBucket = FindBucketByValue(value);
                if (valueBucket != null)
                {
                    throw new InvalidOperationException(
                        $"Duplicate value {value} on key {key} and {valueBucket.Key}");
                }
                bucket.Values.Add(value);
            }
            buckets.Add(key, bucket);
            foreach (var value in values)
            {
                elements.Add(value, key);
            }
        }
    }

    class Bucket : IGrouping<TKey, TElement>
    {
        public TKey Key { get; }
        public IEnumerator<TElement> GetEnumerator() => Values.GetEnumerator();
        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => GetEnumerator();
        internal ICollection<TElement> Values { get; }

        internal Bucket(TKey key)
        {
            Key = key;
            Values = new List<TElement>();
        }
    }
}
```

---

### Questions

- Is this a useful type of collection?
- Is this collection implementing immutability correctly?

Comment: What's the concrete purpose / context to use that?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Any situation that requires a unique set of values, where the values are linked to a key. The way I would use it today, is to store the results of an Exact Cover Problem solution, to verify the solution is a correct keyed set.

Comment: I think the `Contains` method should be renamed `ContainsKey` since (1) it calls `buckets.ContainsKey` and (2) there is also a `ContainsValue` method so the rename adds clarity.

Comment: @RickDavin You are right, that would take away any ambiguity.

Comment: @RickDavin Unfortunately, _Contains_ is part of the _ILookup_ interface I'm implementing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a couple of thoughts

- `FindBucketByKey` and `FindBucketByValue` should be implemented as `TryGetSomething` because you already are doing this anyway internally and what is most important, it would save you from a ton of `null`-checks all over the place. Nobody likes them.
- `Set` should be called `Initialize`
- This one is funny:

  - `if (x == null)` + `throw` means do not use `{}` whereas
  - `if (x != null)` + `throw` means use `{}` ;-)
- You should not initialize `values` with `= new HashSet<TElement>(entry.Value);` as this could change their order. Groupings don't do this so this behavior would be unexpected. You are also not using any other features of a `HashSet` as I find using `Distict` would be more appropriate and would maintain the order of values.
- `Bucket` would be easier to use and implement if it was derived from `List<T>`.
- Use more linq. You know I like linq so I when I see how `Set` is implemented I feel the same way as [@VisualMelon](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/39858/visualmelon) when he sees tuples :-P. This is how I imagine this method doing its main job:

  ```
  var result =
      from x in Data()
      from y in x.Value
      group x.Key by y into g
      select g;
  ```

  This would give you groups for each element where you later could check whether any of the groups contains more than one element. With that, you could identify **all** duplicates and not only the first two and of course the implementation would become much simpler too. This would also be a lot more helpful as with multiple bugs you would need to run the code multiple time to discover every one of them.

Comment: I didn't even notice my subconscious (consistent :p) handling of parenthesis there o_O

Comment: Do you think this class could be useful as API or is it too specific for my use case?

Comment: @dfhwze I think this is quite useful... for example it could be used as a command identifier and the values as its aliases or tags. Or in any other use case where there is a name and some aliases/tags. I've had a lot of them recently so I think I'll borrow form it.